# Showing independence of $\{1,\cos x, \sin x, \ldots, \cos nx, \sin nx\,,\ldots\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Showing independence of $\{1,\cos x, \sin x, \ldots, \cos nx, \sin nx\,,\ldots\}$

There's infinitely many terms so I'm not sure how to do the definition I'm familiar with, like $\alpha(1)+\beta\cos x+\gamma \sin x+\ldots+\psi\cos nx +\mu\sin nx=0\implies \alpha=\beta=\ldots=\psi=\mu=0$

Any hints to get started?

Comment: Are you sure there's an infinite number of terms?

Comment: Its the same, just pick a finite number of terms.

Comment: Easier perhaps to show that they are all orthogonal, from which linear indep follows. What's the underlying vector space, $C[-\pi, \pi]$? If so, integrate each pair over the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$

Comment: An infinite set is linearly independent if every finite subset of it is linear independendent

Comment: I think the "infinite number of terms" refers to $x$.

Comment: Orthogonal makes no sense unless you have some added structure. You can add the structure, of course...

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422347/how-to-prove-that-the-set-sinx-sin2x-sinmx-is-linearly-indepe

Comment: @rschwieb: That's very interesting! I didn't know I could prove independence with integrals.

Comment: @Jon: You can use any tricks you want.

Comment: @Jon It might be better to think of it as "proving independence with an inner product." and "Learning there is an inner product defined by an integral." Otherwise it sounds a bit like a weird trick that makes a huge jump :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key results are $\int_0^{2 \pi} \sin (mt) \sin (nt)dt = \begin{cases} 0, & n \neq m \\
\pi, & n=m\end{cases}$,
$\int_0^{2 \pi} \sin (mt) \cos (nt) dt = 0$ and
$\int_0^{2 \pi} \cos (mt) \cos (nt)dt  = \begin{cases} 0, & n \neq m \\
\pi, & n=m\end{cases}$.

Now suppose you have constants $\alpha_k, \beta_k$ such that
$f(x) = \alpha_0 + \sum_{k=1}^m \alpha_k \cos (kx) + \sum_{k=1}^n \beta_k \sin (kx) = 0$.

Then $\int_0^{2\pi} f(x) dx = 2 \pi \alpha_0 = 0$,
$\int_0^{2\pi} f(x) \cos(lx) dx = \pi \alpha_l = 0$
and
$\int_0^{2\pi} f(x) \sin(lx) dx = \pi \beta_l = 0$.
Hence the set is linearly independent.

Comment: What are the $l$'s in the last passage of text? Are they arbitrary integers?

Comment: Arbitrary non-zero integers. By integrating $f$ multiplied by the appropriate function over $[0,2 \pi]$ you can  'pick out' the relevant multiplier.

Answer (score 0):

Showing that they are orthogonal by integrating would be sufficient. Then a linear combination cannot be 0 because taking the integral with a product of one of the terms is nonzero.