# Prove that sinusoidal waves with different frequency are orthogonal

Tags: orthogonality

Obviously, sin(nx) and cos(nx), where n are integers, are orthogonal, since integrating from -pi to pi gives 0 if n are different.

However, how do I show that, if n are not integers, sin(nx) and cos(nx) are still orthogonal for different values of n? (Or, in fact, are they orthogonal if n are not integers?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product of an odd function ($\sin(nx)$) and an even function ($\cos(nx)$) is odd. Therefore, for any $L>0$,
$$\int_{-L}^{L}\sin(nx)\cos(nx)\,dx=0\,.$$

Comment: What about between sines? For example, are sin(1.2x) and sin(3.3x) orthogonal? (Sorry for the ambiguity in my question)

Comment: No, it's not true between sines in general. $\sin(n\pi x/L)$ and $\sin(m\pi x/L)$ are orthogonal on $\left[-L,L\right]$ only when $n,m\in\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: Is it true, though, that all sines are linearly independent? If so, is there a proof?

Comment: Yes, I think it's true that the set $\{\sin(kx):k\geq 0\}$ is linearly independent, but I'm not sure of the proof. Possibly you can generalise Hurkyl's answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422347/how-to-prove-that-the-set-sinx-sin2x-sinmx-is-linearly-indepe