# Does there exist smooth functions $f_i,g_i \in C^{\infty} (\mathbb R)$ such that $\sin (xy) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n}f_i (x) g_i (y)$ for all $x,y\ $?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, smooth-functions

> Does there exist smooth functions $f_i,g_i \in C^{\infty} (\mathbb R)$ such that $\sin (xy) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n} f_i (x) g_i (y)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb R\ $?

I don't think it's true but couldn't able to conclude it properly. Any help in this regard would be warmly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Interesting question. What does differentiation tell you?

Comment: I find that $x = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n} f_i (x) g_i' (0)$ and $y = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n} f_i' (0) g_i (y)$ from the expressions $x \sin (xy)  = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n} f_i' (x) g_i (y)$ and $y \sin (xy) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n} f_i (x) g_i' (y).$

Comment: Interesting. I had in mind an identity for all $x,y$. Your formula may be helpful.

Comment: Differentiate again?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Taking $y = 1,..., n+1$ implies that $\sin x, \sin 2x, ... , \sin((n+1)x)$ are a subset an $n$-dimensional space of functions. This will contradict that these functions are linearly independent.

Comment: Nice idea. Much more straightforward than the direction I was headed.

Comment: +1. I'm thinking the same thing as you. :)

Comment: @Zarrax$:$ How to show that they are linearly independent?

Comment: @AnilBagchi.  It's been done several times on this site, including https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422347/how-to-prove-that-the-set-sinx-sin2x-sinmx-is-linearly-indepe

Comment: Nice answer. +1

Comment: The direction I was headed was using the approach of the 12-vote answer there :)

Comment: @TedShifrin$:$ It is equally nice. But before that we have to argue along the lines of Zarrax.

Comment: Best 1-liner in quite a while.